# UUID fails unit pytest due to formatting?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am returning a user's UUID in my serializier and this works fine. However, when writing a unit test to test this return the test fails despite them being called the same way. Below is a simplified version of my code.

My serializers.py:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_sso = serializers.SerializerMethodField("get_user_sso")

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = (
            "user_sso",
        )

    def get_user_sso(self, user):
        return user.profile.sso_id
```

My unit test in test_views.py

```
class TestUserAPIView(BaseAPIViewTest):
    factory = factories.UserFactory

    def expected_response(self, user):
        return {
            "user_sso": user.profile.sso_id,
        }
```

The failed test message (the user generated from a factory is the top one):

```
E         -   'user_sso': UUID('f696d740-bdd5-43a3-8f58-406b7a1e117d')},
E         ?               -----                                      -
E         +   'user_sso': 'f696d740-bdd5-43a3-8f58-406b7a1e117d'},
```

How do I make this test pass?

I do not have the word 'UUID(' at the begining of my current output which looks to be the problem but I'm not sure how to remove this without everything making a string? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take the outcome of the `str(…)` as response, otherwise it will take the UUID itself, so:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_sso = serializers.SerializerMethodField("get_user_sso")
    
    # …
    
    def get_user_sso(self, user):
        return str(user.profile.sso_id)
```